# Continuously adding to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have this function that makes changes in the dictionary.

```
    a_dict = {"car": ["audi"], 
             "company": ["apple"]}

     def add_dict(vehicle,brand,stuff):
         for keyword in stuff:
            if keyword == vehicle:
                 if brand not in stuff[keyword]: 
                    stuff[keyword].append(brand) 
                    break 
            else:
                stuff[vehicle] = [brand] 
                break 
     add_dict("car","bmw",a_dict)      

    print(a_dict)
```

This code will add "bmw" to the key "car". However, when I run the code again, using for example "mercedes" instead of bmw, it resets the dictionary to the first one. I want it to continue to add the updated list.

Comment: If you shut down your program and start it again, the memory will be cleared and any data will be lost. You can save it to a file if you want to use it again on subsequent runs.

Comment: Is this inside some loop or a complete file? If it's a complete file then the lists gets reset every time you run the file. Hence you see it as it has replaced something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the `else` clause fires if there is a at least one key that does not match `vehicle`. Fix it like this:

```
def add_to_dict(product_type, brand, product_dict):
    if product_type in product_dict:
        product_dict[product_type].append(brand)
    else:
        product_dict[product_type] = [brand]

product_dict = {}
add_to_dict("car", "audi", product_dict)
add_to_dict("car", "mercedes", product_dict)
add_to_dict("phone", "apple", product_dict)

print(product_dict)
# Output:
# {"car": ["audi","mercedes"], "phone": ["apple"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code again any changes you made will be reset. If you want data to be persistent between runs then you have to save it to a file. For this you can use `json`.

```py
import json
import os

from fastapi import datastructures

DATA_FILE = "data.json"


def load_dict():
    if not os.path.isfile(DATA_FILE):
        return {"car": ["audi"], "company": ["apple"]}
    with open(DATA_FILE, "r") as json_file:
        return json.load(json_file)


def save_dict(stuff):
    with open(DATA_FILE, "w+") as json_file:
        json.dump(stuff, json_file)


def add_dict(vehicle, brand, stuff):
    for keyword in stuff:
        if keyword == vehicle:
            if brand not in stuff[keyword]:
                stuff[keyword].append(brand)
                break
        else:
            stuff[vehicle] = [brand]
            break


a_dict = load_dict()
print(a_dict)

add_dict("car", "bmw", a_dict)
print(a_dict)

save_dict(a_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

Create new function, edit_dict: With this you can amend the new keys and values to the dictionary(preferred way)

OR

Either add another add_dict call for Mercedes to amend to your dictionary (not preferred way)

Comment: Why would re-using the same function not be preferred?

Comment: why would you want to write same line of code again and again, when its not meaningful anyways. What if new line has to be added for Audi or Nissan ? Essentially the function call should be made as many times the key needs to be added. However, its developer choice how the code should be written. Though there are better ways to do, as said.

Comment: If the choice is to add another call to a existing function or to make two different functions and call both I would always prefer to call a function twice

Comment: As said, its personal choice. You can keep writing same line of code again and again to keep glare 'n' of times in your code OR make it efficient to maintain

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. Maybe what you meant to say is that but right now the post makes no sense and appears to say the opposite

Comment: The answer provided was specific to this question only. That's why my first choice was to create a new function, to Edit the dictionary and maintain it. Never mind .. someone downvote me anyways.

Comment: I would be happy to upvote if you edited your answer to be more clear

Comment: Its alright. Unsure who downvote it. Probably its trend here. I am new to this community and still learning. Cheers.